# Is there a package to implement this style of "Register diagrams with field descriptions"

Tags: diagrams

I read ARM spec, and found some register diagrams with the following style. I want to know how to implement it? Is there any exist packages? I already known a package named with "register", but the following style is better in my eyes. Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you looked at the package `bytefield`? It supports typesetting the bit numbers as superscripts. If not already installed, see [https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield](https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) .

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have looked the package bytefield, but its style is not like the picture in this attachment. Is there any way to change the default style of bytefield?

Answer (score 2):

A vanilla TikZ solution with a customized `\foreach` parser that allows a comma separated list of options without the need to protect them from the `\foreach` parser.

The following shortcuts are defined there:

- `h` (for half) adds the double tildes to the box and halves the width of the node.
- `w` (for width) sets the width of the box manually (as a factor of `bytefield/bit width`)
- `bits = <start> to <end>` sets the labels and the width of the box in relation to the number of bits.
- `bit = <number>` is similar to `bits` but sets only one label and the width is set to `1`.

To be able to use a `pic` as a `label` the key `pic` is needed. (Internally, a `pic` uses the same code as a `node` just with a flag set to true, too.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse, libertine}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /tikz/pic/.code=\tikz@node@is@pictrue,
  /pgf/foreach/xparser Om/.style={xparser={O{}}{{##1}/{##2}}},
  /pgf/foreach/xparser/.code 2 args=%
    \DeclareDocumentCommand\pgffor@scan@custom
      {#1u,}{\def\pgffor@value{#2}\pgffor@scanned}%
    \def\pgffor@scan{\pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgffor@stop
      \pgffor@scanone\pgffor@scan@custom}}
\newcommand{\tikzBytefield}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=bytefield going left,
  node distance=+-.5\pgflinewidth,
  bytefield/bit width/.initial=8pt,
  every label/.append style={node font=\small, inner ysep=.1em},
  inner xsep=.1em,
  every bytefield/.append style={
    draw, text height=+.7\baselineskip, text depth=+0pt,
    h/.style={
      label={[pic, rotate=90]north:dbltld},
      label={[pic, rotate=90]south:dbltld},
      bytefield/bit width/.expanded=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bytefield/bit width})/2},
    w/.style={
      minimum width={max(
          (####1)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bytefield/bit width},
          width("M")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}))}},
    bits/.style args={####1 to ####2}{
      w={1+(####2)-(####1)},
      label={[anchor=south west]north west:####2},
      label={[anchor=south east]north east:####1}},
    bit/.style={w=1, label={[anchor=south]north:####1}}},
  dbltld/.pic={
    \fill[white][yshift=+1pt]
      (-2pt, 0pt) to[out=70, in=180] (-1pt,  1pt) cos ( 0pt,  0pt)
      sin ( 1pt, -1pt) to[out=0, in=-120] ( 2pt,  0pt)
      [yshift=+-2pt] -- (2pt, 0pt) to[out=-120, in=0] ( 1pt,  -1pt)
      cos ( 0pt,  0pt) sin ( -1pt, 1pt) to[out=180, in=70] ( -2pt,  0pt) -- cycle;
    \draw[yshift=+1pt]
      (-2pt, 0pt) to[out=70, in=180] (-1pt,  1pt) cos ( 0pt,  0pt)
      sin ( 1pt, -1pt) to[out=0, in=-120] ( 2pt,  0pt)
      [yshift=+-2pt] (2pt, 0pt) to[out=-120, in=0] ( 1pt,  -1pt)
      cos ( 0pt,  0pt) sin ( -1pt, 1pt) to[out=180, in=70] ( -2pt,  0pt);},#1]
\sffamily
\foreach[xparser Om] \Options/\Text in {#2}
\node[on chain=bytefield,every bytefield,style/.expand once=\Options]{\Text};
#3
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\tikzBytefield{%
  [bits =  0 to  7, h] Aff0,
  [bits =  8 to 15, h] Aff1,
  [bits = 16 to 23, h] Aff2,
  [bit  = 24],
  [bits = 25 to 29, h] RES0,
  [bit  = 30]          U,
  [bit  = 31],
  [bits = 32 to 39, h] Aff3,
  [bits = 40 to 63, h] RES0%
}{
  \path[node distance=1em, to path={-|(\tikztotarget)}, shorten >=1pt]
    node[below right=of bytefield-begin] {MT} edge (bytefield-4)
    node[below left=of bytefield-end] {RES1} edge (bytefield-7);
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]