# Use the bytefield package within tikz and refer to bitboxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, bytefield

I'm using the [bytefield](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/bytefield/bytefield.pdf) package to draw protocol specifications.
Is there a ways to use the package within a tikzpicture environment and refer to bitboxes the way you can refer to nodes using anchors.

Specifically, I would like to draw arrows pointing at different bitboxes using e.g. `\draw[<-] (bitbox.south) -- ++(0,-3);`, where `bitbox.south` refers to the south-anchor of one specific bitbox.

As an example consider this picture and the RES1 and MT annotation.
[image]

The picture is from the [this stackoverflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618047/is-there-a-package-to-implement-this-style-of-register-diagrams-with-field-desc) question, where a satisfying result is achieved with a vanilla-tikz solution.
However I would like to keep using the bytefield package to keep a consistent look across all figures.

Comment: You can try with `tikzmark` package

Comment: Could you maybe come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the code for the above diagram using the `bytefield` package (without the attached lines in question) or, better even, the concrete use case you're after? I don't know how to use that package and I am unsure how you would get the wiggly lines positioned.